# Summations and products in F#

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, mathematics, f#

I was bored, and looking to do something that involved anonymous functions, and it was suggested by [@Quill](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62429/quill), that I [create a summation function](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24692900#24692900). I decided to also include a product function as well to top the whole thing off.

For those who don't know, a summation is usually defined like this:

> $$\sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n)$$

And a product is usually defined like this:

> $$\prod_{n=a}^{b}f(n)$$

I'd like to know the following things:

- Am I doing this in a proper functional way?
- Is there a way to reduce the repetitiveness of the code?
- Is it okay to use `List.fold` to multiply all the elements of a list together? Is there a better way?
- Am I violation any style guidelines?
- Anything else?

Here's the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Find the summation in a specific range, given
/// a specific function.
/// </summary>
let summation func low high =
    let function_result_set: int list = [for x in low..high do yield x |> func]
    let result = function_result_set |> List.sum
    result

/// <summary>
/// Find the product in a specific range, given
/// a specific function.
/// </summary>
let product func low high =
    let function_result_set: int list = [for x in low..high do yield x |> func]
    let result = function_result_set |> List.fold (*) 1
    result
```

And finally, here's a few tests:

> ```
> [<EntryPoint>]
> let main argv =
>     System.Console.WriteLine(summation (fun n -> n) 1 10)
>     System.Console.WriteLine(product (fun n -> n) 1 10)
>     System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
>     0
> ```

And here's the desired output from the above tests:

> ```
> 55
> 3628800
> ```

Comment: Are products like doing factorials the opposite way so it acts more like summation?

Comment: @KingCodeFish A product is like a summation, except you're doing multiplication, rather than addition.

Comment: @KingCodeFish Think of it like `1 * 2 * 3 .... 9 * 10` rather than `1 + 2 + 3 ... 9 + 10`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I was just wondering if it's like doing factorials backwards.

Comment: @KingCodeFish No, I don't think so.

Comment: Because in factorials you do `10 * 9 * 8 ... * 3 * 2 * 1`. This looks like you do it the same way but start from 1 and go to `n`.

Comment: The usual convention is that the sum of no elements is 0 and the product of no elements is 1. Does your code do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with `summation`,

> ```
> let summation func low high =
>     let function_result_set: int list = [for x in low..high do yield x |> func]
>     let result = function_result_set |> List.sum
>     result
> ```

First of all, we can remove `result`

```
let summation func low high =
    let function_result_set: int list = [for x in low..high do yield x |> func]
    function_result_set |> List.sum
```

Next, we don't need to construct a list containing `func(low)` .. `func(high)`; we can instead operate over a [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx), meaning we don't have to have all those values in memory at once.

```
let summation func low high =
    let function_result_set = Seq.map func { low .. high }
    function_result_set |> Seq.sum
```

Now we can make it a bit more succinct

```
let summation func low high =
    Seq.map func { low .. high } |> Seq.sum
```

Finally, we can make it more generic by using [statically resolved type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/dd548046.aspx). At the moment, if we have a call to `summation` like this:

```
printfn "%d" <| summation id 1 10
```

then `summation` will be constrained to be of type `(int -> int) -> int -> int -> int`. We can fix this by making the function `inline`:

```
let inline summation func low high =
    Seq.map func { low .. high } |> Seq.sum
```

Now  `summation` has type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'a -> 'b` and the following code will compile:

```
printfn "%d" <| summation id 1 10
printfn "%f" <| summation id 1.0 10.0
```

Similar comments hold for `product`, but with two additional things:

- To make it generic we need to get the `One` property of the type `^a`, and
- I've used the checked version of `*` to check for overflow

```
let inline product func low high : ^a =
    Seq.map func { low .. high } |> Seq.fold Checked.(*) LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne< ^a >
```